# Multi language apps in Android Market - screenshots for more than one language?

Tags: android, localization, google-play

In Apple iTunes app market one can have separate screenshots for each language - in Android I can't find it.

**Is there really only one set of screenshots per app and only the description can be localized?**

Or did I miss something here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are correct. The localization support is only for descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information. As I see now, May 2018, you can add localized screenshots in description in Google Play Console.